# How to export multiple graphs/plots per code block in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

If my R code, which plots several graphs, is contained within one babel code block in org-mode, is it possible to export all of the graphs and display them in the `#+RESULT` section after evaluating the code?

- Using Spacemacs 200.9@25.1.1, Org-mode v.9.0.5, ESS and R 3.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [scimax's ob-ipython extensions](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-org-babel-ipython.el), as described [here](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2017/01/29/ob-ipython-and-inline-figures-in-org-mode/).

Quoting the author:

> I wrote one new function that writes the base64 data out to a
>   temporary file and returns a link to it. Then, I modified the
>   org-babel-execute:ipython function to append these links onto the
>   output.

The code is written for SRC blocks targetying ipython, but you can *probably* modify it so that it works for R in the same way. None of the ideas in the implementation seem to be specific to Python.

The [scimax ob-ipynb exporter](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/ox-ipynb.el) already offers support for R.

Comment: I think this would only work if you use R via Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to export multiple graphs per one `#+RESULTS`.

But I might export multiple graphs, or handle multiple inline images within org-mode, by a dirty way.

Just save graph files by `png()`, `pdf()`, etc.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :results output :exports none
d<-1:5
dd<-data.frame(cbind(x=d, y=d^2, z=d^3))
for(i in 1:3){
    png(paste0("tmp",i,".png"))
    plot(dd[,i],type="b",pch=16,col=i,cex=i,main=paste0("tmp",i))
    dev.off()}
#+END_SRC
```

Then, just make links for each graphic files by hands ;)

If you change the data, such as `d<-1:10`, and execute the source code block by `C-c C-c`, you can see multiple inline images reflect the results simultaneously.

Making links with numbering are stupid simple tasks, I'm sure Emacs Lisp handle numbering tasks without difficulty!

```
#+CAPTION: tmp1
#+NAME: tmp1
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 4cm
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 360
[[file:tmp1.png]]

#+CAPTION: tmp2
#+NAME: tmp2
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 4cm
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 360
[[file:tmp2.png]]

#+CAPTION: tmp3
#+NAME: tmp3
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 4cm
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 360
[[file:tmp3.png]]
```